# Fetch first image URL from post and set as featured image URL

Tags: post-thumbnails

I would like the theme to fetch the first image URL in the post area and display it as the featured image. This came from an old Affiliates WordPress theme `functions.php` file. This company has closed down.

This is the code I am dealing with:

```
function pixr_get_thumb( $post )
{
    $wprobot = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "pixr_wpr_thumb", true );
    $wpzon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "amzn_MediumImageURL", true );
    $goliath = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "amazon-image-url", true );
    $reviewazon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "ReviewAZON_MediumImage", true );
    $amaniche = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "product_image", true );
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) )
    {
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( );
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, "blog-thumb", true );
        $image_url = $image_url[0];
    }
    $manual = $image_url;
    $pixrdefault = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "pixr_thumb", true );
    $nothumb = get_bloginfo( "template_directory" )."/assets/img/nothumb.png";
    if ( $wprobot )
    {
        $thumb = $wprobot;
    }
    else if ( $wpzon )
    {
        $thumb = $wpzon;
    }
    else if ( $goliath )
    {
        $thumb = $goliath;
    }
    else if ( $reviewazon )
    {
        $thumb = $reviewazon;
    }
    else if ( $amaniche )
    {
        $thumb = $amaniche;
    }
    else if ( $manual )
    {
        $thumb = $manual;
    }
    else if ( $pixrdefault )
    {
        $thumb = $pixrdefault;
    }
    else
    {
        $thumb = $nothumb;
    }
    return $thumb;
}

function pixr_azon_thumb( )
{
    global $post;
    $thumb = pixr_get_thumb( $post );
    echo $thumb;
}

function pixr_get_image( $post )
{
    $wprobot = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "pixr_wpr_image", true );
    $wpzon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "amzn_LargeImageURL", true );
    $goliath = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "amazon-image-url-large", true );
    $reviewazon = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "ReviewAZON_LargeImage", true );
    $amaniche = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "image_large_1", true );
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) )
    {
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( );
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, "product-large", true );
        $image_url = $image_url[0];
    }
    $manual = $image_url;
    $pixrdefault = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "pixr_image", true );
    $nothumb = get_bloginfo( "template_directory" )."/assets/img/nothumb.png";
    if ( $wprobot )
    {
        $image = $wprobot;
    }
    else if ( $wpzon )
    {
        $image = $wpzon;
    }
    else if ( $goliath )
    {
        $image = $goliath;
    }
    else if ( $reviewazon )
    {
        $image = $reviewazon;
    }
    else if ( $amaniche )
    {
        $image = $amaniche;
    }
    else if ( $manual )
    {
        $image = $manual;
    }
    else if ( $pixrdefault )
    {
        $image = $pixrdefault;
    }
    else
    {
        $image = $nothumb;
    }
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: you can also use of this plugin, this is very fast and easy: https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-set-first-image-as-featured/ i install this plugin and all is done.

Answer (score 0):

First, paste this function on your functions.php file.

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('//i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Once done, you can simply call the function within the loop to display the first image from the post:

```
echo catch_that_image();
```